# An element is only added to the first item in the list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a simple to-do list in Javascript and I'm currently stuck. I want to add a remove button to every item that appears on the list, but the button is added only to the first item. Could you help?

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton")
const list = document.getElementById("mainList")
const li = document.createElement("li");
const removeButton = document.createElement("button")
removeButton.innerText = "remove"

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = input.value;
  list.append(li);
  li.append(removeButton)
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To-do list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To-do list</h1>
  <h2>Type your tasks below:</h2>
  <input type = "text" id = "input"/>
  <button type="button" name="button" id = "submitButton">Submit</button>
  <ol id = "mainList"></ol>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
removeButton = document.createElement("button")
```

each time you want to create a button

Your code becomes:

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  removeButton = document.createElement("button");
  removeButton.innerText = "remove";
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = input.value;
  list.append(li);
  li.append(removeButton)
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine now :)

Comment: In addition. You are using the same object instance of the removeButton over and over. Which will cause javascript to think there is only 1 button. You need to create new instances of your elements, especially for interacting with it inside your eventListener. Tip: all your dynamic elements should be new instances.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved your issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton")
const list = document.getElementById("mainList")

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // For every item, you must create a button and configure it
  const removeButton = document.createElement("button");
  removeButton.textContent = "remove"
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = input.value;
  list.append(li);
  li.append(removeButton)
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To-do list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To-do list</h1>
  <h2>Type your tasks below:</h2>
  <input type = "text" id = "input"/>
  <button type="button" name="button" id = "submitButton">Submit</button>
  <ol id = "mainList"></ol>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Of course they don't. The question asked how to create a button for each task, not how to make the buttons work. That's up to the OP to continue to work on.